# Samplesize 8 or 16?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, record, capture

I try to record sound from my pc audio device. I can hear the recorded sound  only when I set samplesize to 8 but  when I set the samplesize to 16 , the recorded sound is only a whistle. why? 
here is the code

```
void audioprocess::startRecording()
 {
outputFile.setFileName("C:/Users/Rem/Documents/Qtproject/remaudio.wav");
outputFile.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly );

QAudioFormat format;
// set up the format you want, eg.
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setSampleRate(8000);
format.setChannelCount(1);
format.setSampleSize(8);

format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);
audioInput = new QAudioInput(format);

QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
qWarning()<<"default format not supported try to use nearest";
format = info.nearestFormat(format);
```

}

```
QTimer::singleShot(120000, this, SLOT(stopRecording()));
audioInput->start(&outputFile);

 // Records audio for 120000ms
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your player recognises your input format? Try downloading a program called audacity and play "look at it" there.

Comment: Audacity can import raw audio too, in case you did not write any header.

Comment: when you change sample size to 16, you should also change sample type to signed int.

Answer (score 2):

The whistle is probably because every second sample is zero. That means you get a periodic signal at exactly half the sample frequency.

Now what does your code actually do? You haven't shown us the definition of `outputFile`, but the code snippet is almost literally taken from [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaudioinput.html#details). And it defines `outputFile` as a QFile. The file there is called `test.raw`, and for good reason. Raw files lack a header. Thus it's impossible to determine their sample size.

Answer (score 1):

Finally a question that's in my area of expertise. When it comes to audio development, there are a lot of factors to include into how to program an application. One of those specifically is hardware capabilities. My guess is that your audio device is being sampled too quickly and the higher end bits are just random data.

I would try to increase the sample size, the actual number of frames of audio that are being sampled before being processed, to allow the system to actually buffer the audio and process it while the audio device is receiving new audio input.

Another problem may be the Endianness of your processor. This would usually be an issue if you are on a PowerPC. Or developing for an embedded system that runs on a big Endian processor.

Comment: Considering "PC audio" and "C:/Users/Rem..." I'm fairly sure this is not a PowerPC nor an embedded CPU.

Comment: You're probably right. I don't think so either, but i edited that in be cause that would be another reason for the 8 bit to 16 bit issues.

Comment: "Sampled too quickly and the higher end bits are random data"? Are you equating sample rate to bit depth? And why would the solution for sampling too quickly be to "increase the sample rate"?

Comment: My mistake, I let a typo slip. I changed "sample rate" to "sample size". You're right, sample rate doesn't equal bit depth. But in my experience, especially on lower end audio systems or high latency devices, it's possible to have the higher bits unbuffered. That depends on how the driver handles the audio input and buffering. Unfortunately, not all drivers are made the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess here that you are leaving the sample type as unsigned int and only setting the bit depth to 16. Conventionally, 8 bit waveforms are unsigned while 16 bits are signed. Try patching in the following:

```
format.setSampleSize(16);

format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
```